# Please help on declaring int, checking value and do something in onClick

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I declared an int with a 0 value:

```
int orangeFruit = 0;
```

In this onClick, check if orangeFruit equals to 0, then play mySound, and change orangeFruit to 1,

if orangeFruit 1, play mySoundb, then change orangeFruit to 0 again.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if(orangeFruit == 0) {
                orangeFruit = 1; //set orangeFruit to 1
                mySound.start(); //play sound 1     

            } if(orangeFruit == 1) {
                orangeFruit = 0; //set orangeFruit back to 0
                mySoundb.start(); //play sound 2
            }
                            }
```

it didn't work, are there any way to set int value, am I doing something wrong?
I tried increase or decrease orangeFruit with += and -=, it didn't work.

Any clues would help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a slight change to your second if:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if(orangeFruit == 0) {
            orangeFruit = 1; //set orangeFruit to 1
            mySound.start(); //play sound 1     
        } else if (orangeFruit == 1) {
            orangeFruit = 0; //set orangeFruit back to 0
            mySoundb.start(); //play sound 2
        }
}
```

The else does the trick. Without the else, the program will step into the second if right after having finished the first one, playing both sounds after only one click.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `if` statement is *overriding* the first one, so all two if are executed.

You need to use `if / else if` statement otherwise both if statements are executed.

```
        if(orangeFruit == 0) {
            orangeFruit = 1; //set orangeFruit to 1
            mySound.start(); //play sound 1     

        } else if(orangeFruit == 1) {
            orangeFruit = 0; //set orangeFruit back to 0
            mySoundb.start(); //play sound 2
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a silly mistake in your code. Initializing using the following code is correct

```
int orangeFruit = 0;
```

the you are using if statements to check the value of `orangeFruit`

```
if(orangeFruit == 0) {
                orangeFruit = 1; //set orangeFruit to 1
                mySound.start(); //play sound 1     

            }
```

This will check if your `orangeFruit`'s value is `0` then play the sound 1 and set `orangeFruit` to `1`. Then in second if statement you are checking if `orangeFruit` is `1` which it is since you set in the code above.

Instead of if in the next condition use `else if` which makes sure that this condition is only to be checked if the first condition is not true.

```
else if(orangeFruit == 1) {
                orangeFruit = 0; //set orangeFruit back to 0
                mySoundb.start(); //play sound 2
            }
```